# $\zeta(1+it)=0$ implies sum of prime if finite?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Can anyone explain why $\zeta(1+it)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+it}}=0$ will imply $\sum_{\text{p prime}} \frac{1-\Re(-p^{-it})}{p}< \infty?$

Here is what I have so far:

We know $\zeta(s)$ does not have any zeros for $\Re(s) \geq 1.$ So $\zeta(1+it) \not=0.$

Thus, we have,

$\sum_{\text{p prime}}\frac{1-\Re(-p^{-it})}{p}= \sum_{\text{p prime}} \frac{1}{p}-  \sum_{\text{p prime}}\frac{\Re(-p^{-it})}{p}$.

The first sum is known to be infinite and the second one ressembles $\zeta(1+it).$  However, I dont know how to conclude the whole sum is infinite.

Comment: It's surely because $\zeta(1+it)$ is never zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  question edited !